# How to unlink image?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

im using modal bootstrap with codeignitter 4. I can delete the data in database but cannot unlink the image. here my code :

Model :

```
public function deleteProduct($id)
{
    $query = $this->db->table('produk')->delete(array('kode' => $id));
    return $query;
}
```

Controller :

```
 public function delete()
{
    $model = new produkModel();
    $id = $this->request->getPost('kode');
    $produk = $this->produkModel->find($id);
    
    if ($produk['gambar'] != 'default.png') {
      
        unlink('imgproduk/' . $produk['gambar']);
    }
    $model->deleteProduct($id);
    return redirect()->to('/Tabel_Produk');
}
```

i want to delete the image in directory but dont delete the default.img

Comment: looks like a path problem. Are you sue 'imgproduk' is in the same folder as your PHP file? you might want to use an absolute path (e.g. using `FCPATH`) to make sure.

Comment: yeah, when i try always showing error "mysqli_sql_exception #1054
Unknown column 'produk.id' in 'where clause' "

Comment: What is the absolute path for that image?

Comment: im newbie with programming, what i know if you use CI4 you can save your folder image in folder public. i've been trying "public/imgproduk/" and still showing the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Use complete folder path to delete/access image through PHP by using $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] to get server path.

```
 public function delete(){
    $model = new produkModel();
    $id = $this->request->getPost('kode');
    $produk = $this->produkModel->find($id);
    
    if ($produk['gambar'] != 'default.png') {
      
        unlink($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/imgproduk/' . $produk['gambar']);
    }
    $model->deleteProduct($id);
    return redirect()->to('/Tabel_Produk');
}
```

Comment: still showing the same error : Unknown column 'produk.id' in 'where clause' .

Comment: this error is from you query, please check column id in produk or check table is included in query, if possible please share your query